# Let $x(n)=$ product of first $n$ primes.How often is $x(n)$ triangular?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, analytic-number-theory, experimental-mathematics

$x(0)=1$, an empty product, is a triangular number. So are $x(2)=2\times 3=6$, and $x(4)=2\times 3\times 5\times 7=210$.

Comment: I strongly suspect that is all.  If there were more known, there would be a sequence in OEIS and there is not.  For people with the right tools it is an easy search up to very high numbers.  A web search for primorial triangular came up empty.  Somewhere I saw a rule that for Diophantine equations you should expect infinite solutions if the inverses of the powers of the variables sum to more than $1$.  The triangulars go as $n^2$ but the primorials are roughly $n^n$ so we would expect finitely many.

Comment: The "probability" that $N$ is triangular is $\approx 1/\sqrt{N}$, and $\prod_{p \le k} p \approx e^{k}$ thus we are looking at $\prod_{k=K}^\infty Pr(\prod_{p \le k} p \text{ is not triangular}) \approx \prod_{k=K}^\infty Pr(e^{k} \text{ is not triangular}) \approx \prod_{k=K}^\infty (1-\frac{1}{e^{k/2}}) $ which converges (so it $\to 1$ quite fast as $K\to \infty$, and hence we expect there are finitely many triangular primorials). @RossMillikan

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A161620 , it is not known whether there are 6th triangular primordial.

Comment: Also, OP dropped small solutions ($x(1)=2$ and $x(3)=30$ are triangular), that's why @RossMillikan could not find an OEIS sequence.

Comment: $2$ and $30$ are not triangular, they are twice triangular.  The numbers in OEIS A161620 are twice triangular.